# How to draw an inverted element on a layer in KonvaJS

Tags: html5-canvas, konvajs

is there any way to add a shape in KonvaJS which draws outside of it's boundries? Basically a "hole" in the layer, so that I can highlight a spot in the canvas by making everything around a circle darker (black with low opacity).

Any help is much appreciated!

Cheers

Edit:
Here is an image of what I mean (I'm not allowed to embed it yet):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yve2.jpg

I was hoping there might be something like this:

```
Konva.Circle({
  x: 100,
  y: 100,
  radius: 50,
  opacity: 0.3,
  fill: 'black',
  inverted: true
})
```

and this would then in turn "not draw" a circle, but everything around it would then take the given attributes. In this case it would all be darkend a bit besides the circle.

Comment: Do you have a visual demo of what you want?

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45445666/konvajs-clipping-function-but-with-opacity/45546946#45546946) is relevant - in order to clip you need to add a group with a clipping region.

Comment: Basically [this](https://i.imgur.com/gvTqgN0.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a custom shape:

```
const shape = new Konva.Shape({
  width: stage.width(),
  height: stage.height(),
  // what is color of background ?
  fill: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.2)',
  sceneFunc: (ctx, shape) => {
    // draw background
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(shape.width(), 0);
    ctx.lineTo(shape.width(), shape.height());
    ctx.lineTo(0, shape.height());
    ctx.lineTo(0, 0);

    // now cut circle from the background
    // we can do this by useing arc
    const x = 200;
    const y = 200;
    const radius = 10;
    // but it must be counter-clockwise
    // so the last argument true is very important here
    ctx.arc(200, 200, 100, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.fillStrokeShape(shape);
  },

  // remove shape from hit graph, so it is not visible for events
  listening: false
});
```

Demo: https://jsbin.com/tevejujafi/3/edit?html,js,output

Comment: This seems to be pretty much exactly what I need. I don't quite understand how the cutting of the circle is working here. You are drawing a rectangle from corner to corner and then you just draw a circle. But how does the shape know that the circle's inside doesn't belong to the shape? Is it the fillStrokeShape method, which handles this?

Comment: Is this to do with 'non-zero winding' for fill ? See [wikipedia explanation here](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Nonzero-rule).

Comment: Is there a way to remove a different shape instead of an `arc`?